# Календарь и БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть ежедневник, в который записываются какие нибудь записи и сохраняются в БД. 
Но нужно, чтобы это было в виде календаря и причём всё упорядочено. Допустим: "выбрали дату и нам выводит все записи выбранной даты, а если выбрали за целый месяц, то тоже вывести".

Вопрос заключается в том: Как внести весь календарь в БД или есть другой вариант?

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: >Есть ежедневник, в который записываются какие нибудь записи и сохраняются в БД.

>Как внести весь календарь в БД

как-то звучит так что сделайте мне,а то не получается. сначала у тебя все записывается, потом как внести все в БД... ты уж определись в показаниях.

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том: Как внести весь календарь в БД или есть другой вариант?
То есть, нужно ли хранить весь календарь в БД или по другому?

Comment: нужна запись-вносишь. вопрос глупо поставлен. Ты не умеешь вносить данные в БД или тв не умеешь и не понимаешь логики работы того к чему ты стремишься?

как думаешь работает записная бумажная книжка? постоянно новая на каждую запись или на нужной страничке у неё нужная запись? так вот нужная запись на нужной страничке - это сортировка, а вот кол-во записей в ней это кол-во добавленных записей в БД.

Comment: Критика - это хорошо и за неё спасибо.
А если глупо: то из-за того, что говорилось всё "на пример".
Проблема в другой области.....

Answer (score 1):

Не надо вводить весь календарь в БД)

Просто при сохранении записи указывайте ее дату, а при выводе календаря проверяйте на соответствие (`>= начало_месяца AND <= конец_месяца`).

Перед выводом получаете все записи на текущий месяц и выводите все числа, если есть запись на это число - то и ее.

```
<? 
// добавление
$d = 15;
$m = 11;
$y = 2011;
mysql_query('INSERT INTO records (`name`, `text`, `time`) VALUES ("раз", "два", '.strtotime($d.'/'.$m.'/'.$y.' 00:00:00').');');
// получение и вывод
$first = strtotime('1/'.$m.'/'.$y.' 00:00:00');
$last = strtotime(date('t', $first).'/'.$m.'/'.$y.' 00:00:00');
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM records WHERE (`time`>='.$first.' AND `time`<='.$last.');');
$result = array();

while ($event = mysql_fetch_object($res))
  $result[date('d', $event->time)] = $event;

// тут у нас есть массив вида число => событие. 
?>
```

Вывод календаря на php ищите где-нибудь в другом месте, их куча, в т.ч. бесплатных мелких скриптов, типа, например, [здесь](http://www.woweb.ru/load/)

Comment: @Темыч, не разбрасываемся кармой, слева от ответа есть галка ("принять") =)